# Surface Type Cover stops working when rotated

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, windows-10-v1803, microsoft-surface-pro, accelerometer

I'd like to be able to use my Surface Pro 6 in this sort of position:
[image: Man lying in bed on his side, using a MacBook sideways]

The rotation lock button is disabled when the keyboard is connected, so I first disconnected the keyboard and enabled rotation lock, and then reattached it.

However, as soon as I rotate the Surface Pro sideways, even with rotation lock enabled, the Surface keyboard stops working, with any keypresses or touchpad gestures having no apparent effect.

Is there any way to have the keyboard stay responsive? It might be by design that the Surface disables the Type Cover in this position, but that design choice doesn't make any sense to me.

A regular Bluetooth keyboard works fine when the Surface is rotated.

Answer (score 2):

After my initial confusion caused by your image of an Apple computer has passed,
I have looked into the problem.

The earliest reference to it that I found was in the post
[Clip-on keyboard stops working when Surface Pro is rotated](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/clip-on-keyboard-stops-working-when-surface-pro-is/2681835b-d904-4ad2-8aff-ee1e657ac68d),
dating from 2013 (!).

A Microsoft person at that time has promised to pass on this "feature request".
His only suggestion was to connect it via Bluetooth.

Another post from that time,
[auto rotate and on-screen keyboard issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/auto-rotate-and-on-screen-keyboard-issues-surface/4da1584b-0884-4df1-9a02-d2c21e1c31bf),
has offered a workaround that solved the problem for several readers:

- Open Device Manager
- Expand Sensors
- Right click HID Sensor Collection and choose Uninstall and then OK
- Reboot

The above workaround will basically just reinstall the drivers of the sensors
to their latest version.

A later post from 2017,
[Rotation of laptop disables trackpad and keyboard even with tablet mode turned off](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_continuum/rotation-of-laptop-disables-trackpad-and-keyboard/356738f2-98f6-483d-932c-12147299aff0),
has this explanation and workaround, which again worked for some readers
(although not targeted for the Surface Pro it is worth trying):

> When in normal laptop mode (device orientation should be as a normal laptop), I go into the Device Manager and I disable the orientation sensors. On my unit this is under System devices the "Intel(R) Integrated Sensor Solution". In practice this now locks the unit in laptop mode. When I want its normal behavior back, I enable the device again in Device Manager.

Try it. If this helps, it is possible to create scripts for disabling/enabling
the sensors, which you could put up as desktop icons.

Comment: Interestingly, disabling the Intel(R) Integrated Sensor Solution disables autorotation (after a restart), but the keyboard still stops working when rotated. Disabling Firmware > Surface Integrated Sensor Hub doesn't seem to do anything. I don't see any section named Sensor or any drivers named HID Sensor Collection.

Comment: If you do the rotation, then disable the Integrated Sensors and reboot, what happens?

Comment: Reposting a comment from @minosa: 

Disabled both, "HID Sensor Collection V2" under Sensors and then also "Intel Integrated Sensor Solution" which required reboot and after the HID Sensor COllection even disappeared.

Didn't help solve the problem on my Surface Pro newer generation from 2017.

Can't believe Microsoft hasn't solved this yet. This is frustrating, it isn't rocket science but hasn't been solved for years and generations of this piece of hardware.

But Mircosoft pays a whole lot on an entire section of people to figure out what users want.

Comment: windows 11 and still no change.